# OpenId Connect Authentication .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We are trying to authenticate internal users via Azure AD when they visit certain pages. Our servers are not on site, so we are looking for an API where we can just pass the username and password of the user and receive whether they are in our organization and which groups they are apart of. It was possible in framework. Does such a thing exist for .NET Core?

UPDATE:
Thanks for replying! It seems to be giving me the authorization code now and now I'm trying to use this to get a token to then use that access token to get the user's groups (please correct me if I'm going about this the wrong way). My problem is I keep getting a bad request error. I've gone over the parameters a bunch and can't find what I'm missing. Here is my current set up of the API URLS, am I missing something?

```
 string postData = $"{{\"grant_type\":\"{grant_type}\",\"client_id\":\"{client_id}\",\"code\":\"{code}\",\"redirect_uri\":\"{redirect_uri}\",\"client_secret\":\"{client_secret}\"}}";
 string redirectUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type={response_type}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_mode={response_mode}&resource={client_id}";
 string requestUriString = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token";
```

UPDATE 2: I figured out what was wrong, I was passing the post data as a Json String when it needed to be x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Azure AD does not support LDAP. To do what you want, you'll need to use OpenID Connect, authenticate the user with Azure AD, and setup your app registration such that you get their group memberships as claims in the Id token. Though all of them might not fit in the token if there are too many, in which case you'll need to query the user's group memberships from Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc

Comment: Thanks for answering! Once a user goes to the login page and is authenticated, how do I then retrieve that form post data?

Comment: The page will send the user back to your site with an authorization code that you can then exchange in your back-end for an access token, Id token and refresh token. The access tokens allow you to call APIs, the Id token tells you who the user is and th me refresh token allows you to get new access tokens when they expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure this will solve your problem but you might want to have a look at the following .NET Core sample (with MSAL.NET): https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2

This is with the usual disclaimer that we really don't recommend anybody to use username/password. There are other much better possibilities. For the full picture, see https://aka.ms/msal-net-scenarios